# TypeError: Cannot read property 'GlobalWorkerOptions' of undefined in PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc when using React js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, npm, pdf.js, react-pdf

I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'GlobalWorkerOptions' of undefined" in PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc. My code is here,

```
import { pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.87/pdf.js`;
```

I used this to extract text from given a pdf. I use

> npm i react-pdf

npm for this. Help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Change somefile.pdf with your PDF document.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    numPages: null,
    pageNumber: 1,
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    this.setState({ numPages });
  }

  render() {
    const { pageNumber, numPages } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Document
          file="somefile.pdf"
          onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>
        <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer what I expect. I must be able to know, what is the correct way to use **pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc** in react.

Comment: The answer is directly from the documentation. https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf